# ошибка перехода на другую страницу php

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование, backend

Здравствуйте столкнулся с проблемой, что не работает переадресация на другую страницу в php выдает ошибку со скриншота. Как можно исправить?[![

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

ol,
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}


/* Стили текста(Общий) */

.text {
  color: #111;
  font-family: "Oswald";
  padding: .4rem;
}

.table-block {
  border: .09rem solid rgb(255, 166, 0);
  padding: 1rem;
}

table {
  margin: auto;
  border: .3rem solid rgb(255, 166, 0);
  border-radius: .6rem;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 1rem;
}

th {
  border: .2rem solid rgb(255, 166, 0);
  padding: 1rem;
}

.logo {
  width: 20rem;
  height: 15rem;
}

.main-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.table-btn {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.add-btn {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  border: .2rem solid rgb(255, 166, 0);
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  border-radius: .6rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<?php 
    $startReadFilePow = 0;  
    $all = array();
    if (($file = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) { 
        while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ';')) !== FALSE) { 
            $dataFromCSV = array();
            for ($c=0; $c < count($data); $c++) {
                array_push($dataFromCSV, $data[$c]);
            }
            array_push($all, $dataFromCSV);
            $startReadFilePow++;   
        }
        fclose($file);
    }
   

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&family=Oswald:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="style_second.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <section class="main-section">
    <div class="logo-block">
      <img src="images/logo_university.png" alt="" class="logo">
    </div>

    <div class="table-div">
      <table>

        <tr>
          <th class="table-block text">Автор</th>
          <th class="table-block text">Название</th>
          <th class="table-block text">Издание</th>
          <th class="table-block text">Жанр</th>
          <th class="table-block text">Назначение</th>
          <th class="table-block text">Редактировать</th>
          <th class="table-block text">Удалить</th>
        </tr>
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $startReadFilePow; $i++) :?>
        <tr>
          <td class="table-block text">
            <?php echo $all[$i][0] ?>
          </td>
          <td class="table-block text">
            <?php echo $all[$i][1] ?>
          </td>
          <td class="table-block text">
            <?php echo $all[$i][2] ?>
          </td>
          <td class="table-block text">
            <?php echo $all[$i][3] ?>
          </td>
          <td class="table-block text">
            <?php echo $all[$i][4] ?>
          </td>
          <td class="table-block text"><button onclick="" class="table-btn text">Редактировать</button></td>
          <td class="table-block text"><button onclick="" class="table-btn text">Удалить</button></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endfor; ?>
      </table>



      <button onclick="<?php header(" location:index.php "); ?>" name="submit" class="add-btn text" id="btn">Добавить</button>


    </div>
    <div class="logo-block">
      <img src="images/logo_university.png" alt="" class="logo">
    </div>

  </section>
</body>

</html>
<?php ?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: php - выполняется на стороне сервера, его нельзя просто засунуть в html и ждать что произойдет чудо :) я вам вот про это место ```<button onclick="<?php header("location:index.php"); ?>"``` вместо php в этом месте нужно использовать js

Comment: дополнил кодbtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        window.location.href = "list.php";
    })

Comment: но ничего не происходит, он остается на начальной странице

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, измените код согласно его текущего состояния, сейчас не понятно куда и как вы вставили данный код...

Comment: Вот примерно так это должно было бы выглядеть чтоб работать: ```<button onclick="window.location.href = ''" name="submit" class="add-btn text" id="btn">Добавить</button>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вместо этого

`<button onclick="<?php header("location:index.php"); ?>" name="submit" class="add-btn text" id="btn">Добавить</button>`

ставь вот это

`<button onclick="window.location.href = 'ТВОЯ ССЫЛКА';" name="submit" class="add-btn text" id="btn">Добавить</button>`